# How to change the footer

Tags: blocks, footer

How can i fix the footer? I would like the individual blocks next to each other.

Thanks for your answer:)[image]

Comment: its impossible to answer your question without more and detailed information. For the beginning like: Magento Version? What do you have do to get this "result". Maybe some code examples. Please read all articles in the help section about `Asking` http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: Hey Flavio, Do you have a link to live site?  What Magento version are you on?  What theme / skin are you using?

Comment: This is the [link](https://n1njastore.com)
We use Magento 2.1.1

Comment: Can anyone help me please :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem in magento 2.1.0,
I simply changed the css and it worked:
        .footer.content .links{
                               display:flex;}

Also, I gave the class=footerlinks to the unordered list created in each block and added the css
                  .footer.links {
                           display: block !important;}